# Seg fault when assigning a value to a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, segmentation-fault

I am trying to assign a value to a specific index in a vector. I am getting a segmentation fault when attempting to do so. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int sp = -1;            // Stack pointer
int pc = 0;             // Program counter
int fpsp = -1;          // Frame pointer stack pointer
vector<int> rstack;     // Runtime Stack
vector<int> fpstack;    // Frame Pointer Stack

int getInt(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char c, unsigned char d) {
    int i = (d << 24) | (c << 16) | (b << 8) | a;
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
   // Reading size of file
    FILE * file = fopen("Samples/Ground_Truth/interpreter_input.smp", "r+");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int size = ftell(file);
    fclose(file);

    // Reading data to memory array
    file = fopen("Samples/Ground_Truth/interpreter_input.smp", "r+");
    unsigned char * mem = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);
    int bytes_read = fread(mem, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file);
    fclose(file);

    bool halt = 0;
    while(!halt) {
        int i = getInt(mem[pc + 1], mem[pc + 2], mem[pc + 3], mem[pc + 4]);
        rstack[++sp] = i;
        pc += 5;

        halt = 1;
    }
}
```

When trying to perform `rstack[++sp] = i;` I receive a seg fault. However, if I use rstack.push_back(i) it works fine. However, I would like to be able to directly assign this value by referencing the index.

Comment: Are you aware that `push_back` adds a new element to the `std::vector`, while indexing does not do so? Why do you want to do this by indexing rather than correctly with `push_back`?

Comment: Also in C++: 1. Use `new` instead of `malloc`. 2. Use `std::string` instead of allocating `char` buffers dynamically. 3. Use the facilities from `<fstream>` instead of the C library `FILE*`-based IO.

Comment: to amplify @uneven_mark , indexing is only valid if the element in the vector already exists. It doesn't expand the vector by adding elements.

Comment: I wasn't aware that indexing didn't add an element to the vector. I understand now, and thank you for your advice.